# How to revert-back from SSL to non-SSL in Tomcat 6?

Tags: tomcat, ssl, tomcat6

I'm using jsf 2 + jaas + ssl + tomcat 6.0.26

I have in my web site 2 paths:

/faces/protected/* which uses SSL

/faces/unprotected/* which don't uses SSL.

I've put this in my web.xml:

```
<login-config>
        <auth-method>FORM</auth-method>
        <form-login-config>
            <form-login-page>/faces/login.jsp</form-login-page>
            <form-error-page>/faces/error.jsp</form-error-page>
        </form-login-config>
    </login-config>
    <security-constraint>
        <web-resource-collection>
            <web-resource-name>Secure Resource</web-resource-name>
            <description/>
            <url-pattern>/faces/unprotected/*</url-pattern>
            <http-method>GET</http-method>
            <http-method>POST</http-method>
            <http-method>HEAD</http-method>
            <http-method>PUT</http-method>
            <http-method>OPTIONS</http-method>
            <http-method>TRACE</http-method>
            <http-method>DELETE</http-method>           
        </web-resource-collection>
        <auth-constraint>
            <role-name>C</role-name>
        </auth-constraint>          
    </security-constraint>
    <security-constraint>
        <web-resource-collection>
            <web-resource-name>Secure Resource</web-resource-name>
            <description />
            <url-pattern>/faces/protected/*</url-pattern>
            <http-method>GET</http-method>
            <http-method>POST</http-method>
            <http-method>HEAD</http-method>
            <http-method>PUT</http-method>
            <http-method>OPTIONS</http-method>
            <http-method>TRACE</http-method>
            <http-method>DELETE</http-method>
        </web-resource-collection>
        <auth-constraint>
            <role-name>C</role-name>
        </auth-constraint>
        <user-data-constraint>
            <transport-guarantee>CONFIDENTIAL</transport-guarantee>
        </user-data-constraint>     
    </security-constraint>
    <security-role>
        <description> Role Client </description>
        <role-name>C</role-name>
    </security-role>
```

and this is my server.xml:

```
 <Connector port="8080" protocol="HTTP/1.1" 
               maxThreads="400"
               maxKeepAliveRequests="1"
               acceptCount="100"
               connectionTimeout="3000"
               redirectPort="8443"
                compression="on"
                compressionMinSize="2048"
                noCompressionUserAgents="gozilla, traviata"
                compressableMimeType="text/javascript,text/css,text/html, text/xml,text/plain,application/x-javascript,application/javascript,application/xhtml+xml"  />


  <Connector port="8443" protocol="org.apache.coyote.http11.Http11AprProtocol" SSLEnabled="true"
               maxThreads="400" scheme="https" secure="true"
               clientAuth="optional" sslProtocol="TLS" 
               SSLCertificateFile="path/to/crt" 
               SSLCertificateKeyFile="path/to/pem"/>
```

when i enter to protected paths, it switches to HTTPS (port 8443), but when i enter to path /faces/unprotected/somthing... it stays using HTTPS.

what i want is when i enter to unprotected paths, it revert-back to non-SSL communications ( otherwise, i have to re-login again when i set the exact adress in my browser).

What's wrong with my configurations ?

Is there a way so i can do such a thing ?

Is it possible to call the page using  without  asking for authentification second time ?

Comment: simply reinstall it it would be a simpler solution

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, that is the normal behaviour on Tomcat.

Once it moves into https, it will not redirect other URLs back into http, unless the URL explicitly is for http.

If *you really need to*, you would have to write a  [`Filter`](http://download.oracle.com/javaee/6/api/javax/servlet/Filter.html) to check if the URL is not part of the secured pattern, then redirect back to http.

Comment: @mohamida: your `Filter` can check if you are already logged in too

Comment: @mohamida: see http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2521740/java-filter-url-pattern-specific-to-request-params/2521832#2521832 and change the doFilter method to whatever you want to check

Answer (score 1):

If you log in under HTTPS and then move back to HTTP, you are exposing an authenticated cookie to a man-in-the-middle attack.  This is bad.

You should remain in HTTPS for the entire time your session is authenticated.

The compute required to perform SSL is, in comparison to the work your app does, completely trivial.  Just stick with SSL.