# Application-wide filter for authentication Issue

Tags: java, servlets, servlet-filters

I am trying to learn the use of filters. I have created an application-wide filter by specifying url-pattern like this:

```
<filter>
    <display-name>AuthenticationFilter</display-name>
    <filter-name>AuthenticationFilter</filter-name>
    <filter-class>learn.filters.AuthenticationFilter</filter-class>
  </filter>
  <filter-mapping>
    <filter-name>AuthenticationFilter</filter-name>
    <url-pattern>/*</url-pattern>
  </filter-mapping>
```

I have set welome-file to:

```
<welcome-file-list>
       <welcome-file>/WEB-INF/jsp/home.jsp</welcome-file>
</welcome-file-list>
```

My doFilter code is as follows:

```
public void doFilter(ServletRequest request, ServletResponse response, FilterChain chain) throws IOException, ServletException {
    HttpServletRequest req=(HttpServletRequest)request;
    HttpServletResponse res=(HttpServletResponse)response;
    String username=(String)req.getSession().getAttribute("username");
    if(username==null && req.getParameter("username")==null){
        req.getRequestDispatcher("/WEB-INF/jsp/login.jsp").forward(request, response);
    }else{
        String user=req.getParameter("username");
        String pass=req.getParameter("password");
        if(user==null){
            req.getRequestDispatcher("/WEB-INF/jsp/home.jsp").forward(request, response);
        }else{
            if(user.equals(pass)){
                req.getSession().setAttribute("username", user);
                res.sendRedirect("home");
            }
        }
    }
```

This code works fine and authenticates the user, but any extra resources that are on my login.jsp page (like js files) are not imported because every request returns the login page. That means if the user isn't authenticated, I am unable to reach any resource of my web-app like captcha, js, css files. Please advice

Answer (score 0, accepted):

in your doFilter method add a pattern match to skip filtering.

You could have a pattern match for your .js an .css etc and skip them.

You could check [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2521740/java-filter-url-pattern-specific-to-request-params) also

Comment: Great answer. Thanks, I hope there won't be a security issue in that case.

Comment: what kind of security you are refering?

Answer (score 0):

The filter is set to map to -everything-. Perhaps you want to map it to *.jsp only so it doesn't fire for static resources like html files, javascript files, css files, images, etc.

Comment: Are "application-wide" authentication-filters discredited? Should I not use such mappings?